# Bind an event to a element not created yet jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind

I have a button that is not created until you click in a `div`.

I need to add an `onclick` event to that button, but I can't with the `.on()` method. It doesn't work.

```
<section class="span9 cont_llens">
    <div id="llens"></div>
</div>
```

The script generates the blocks inside the `#llens` div. Then if you click a one of these blocks you may see the menu edition, up there it shows up.

So that's the binding I need, `onclick` to this buttons.

See the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/blackersoul/47YvE/

Comment: when you add the button into the html then you add the event...

Comment: @ryanc1256 that can be a rather inefficient method, depending on how many elements are being added.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes it could be, but it sounds like it's just one button so it's not going to compromise the JS Compiler, but it may be the tipping point if his website is very JavaScript heavy, but to me it seems thats not the case here

Comment: @ryanc1256  If I add this metod after creating the buttons, the second time I  click on a bloc and then to a button I alerts me 2 times. as if I'd created 2 function for the same click

Comment: @Blackersoul you can just unbind the event...

Comment: @Blackersoul: Fixed your fiddle. See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $.on function for this function specifying the selector (second parameter).

Read http://api.jquery.com/on/

User like  `$('section').on('click', 'div#llens > button')`

The reason why your code is not working because you are canceling the events via stopPropagation at two places. I have commented that in your fiddle and it is working.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/47YvE/4/